# Do I need to configure the beans in the example below for my Spring Data JDBC project?

Tags: java, spring-data-jdbc

Do I need to configure the beans in the example below for my Spring Data JDBC project?

Even without those beans, I was able to have my repository queries working correctly.

As I understand, NamedParameterJdbcOperations is used only internally to submit SQL statements to the database and that developers don't use it directly.

Would like to get more clarifications on this.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJdbcRepositories
public class SpringDataJdbcApplication extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataJdbcApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() 
    {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    NamedParameterJdbcOperations namedParameterJdbcOperations(DataSource dataSource) 
    { 
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() 
    { 
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you include dependency `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in maven or gradle?

Comment: I had added spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc. It is for Spring Data JDBC, not Spring Data JPA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` in dependencies in Maven or Gradle,By "Convention over configuration" paradigm, you shouldn't need to create any bean at all include the `dataSource` bean. Just `main` method is enough. Those necessary beans will be created automatically.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDataJdbcApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataJdbcApplication.class, args);
    }
    
}
```

and inside application.yml

```
...
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://dbhost/db
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
    max-active: 3
...
```

Comment: The question is about Spring Data JDBC not Spring Data JPA, but the principal idea is correct: These beans get created by Spring Boot just fine.

Comment: Thanks Jens and Chayne for the clarifications.

Comment: Thank you @JensSchauder to correct me. After testing, I just update the answer to be for Spring Data JDBC

Comment: You should also remove the jpa section from `application.yml`